# Zebra printing java

Tags: java, android, zebra-printers

I want to print print a file on  Zebra iM320 but the file has special characters like "ç" and "ë". When I use encoding ISO-8859-1 it prints correctly but the letter is no aligned with the text. I tried everything but nothing works. help

```
String cpclConfigLabel = "! 0 200 200 1320 1\r\n"
            + "PW 575\r\n"
            + "ON-FEED IGNORE\r\n" 
            + "TONE 0\r\n" 
            + "SPEED 3\r\n"
            + "ON-FEED IGNORE\r\n" 
            + "NO-PACE\r\n" 
            + "BAR-SENSE\r\n"
            + "T 7 1 39 190 Masë Plotësuese\r\n";

os.write(EncodingUtils.getBytes(cpclConfigLabel, "ISO-8859-1") );

    os.flush();
    os.close();
```

tried this but nothing:

```
os.write(EncodingUtils.getBytes(cpclConfigLabel, "CP1250"));
```

tried this too:

```
configLabel = cpclConfigLabel.getBytes(Charset.forName("CP1250"));
os.write(configLabel);
```

Comment: Try using UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1

Comment: I used it but doesn't work, The only problem is that the character is not aligned

Comment: how about `os.write(cpclConfigLabel.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));`

Comment: It might be a bit of work, but if you switch the printer to use zpl and utf-8 you would not have this problem.

Comment: @Sanjeev tried that too, not working.

Comment: I still haven't fixed this problem. Anyone has an idea?